# Scala marshal to / unmarshal from JSON

Tags: json, scala, jackson, scala-3

I have some utility code that marshals Scala objects to JSON and vice-versa. It works well, but it has started warning me that `"ScalaObjectMapper is deprecated because Manifests are not supported in Scala3"`. It looks like I should use `ClassTagExtensions` instead, but it's not clear to me how.

Does anyone know how I can change this utility class to use `ClassTagExtensions` and achieve the convenient un/marshalling functionality it provides today?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

object JsonUtil {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  // ScalaObjectMapper is deprecated because Manifests are not supported in Scala3
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

  def toJson(value: Map[Symbol, Any]): String = {
    toJson(value map { case (k, v) => k.name -> v })
  }

  def toJson(value: Any): String = {
    mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
  }

  def toMap[V](json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[V]): Map[String, V] = fromJson[Map[String, V]](json)

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
  }
}

object MarshallableImplicits {

  implicit class Unmarshallable(unMarshallMe: String) {
    def toMap: Map[String,Any] = JsonUtil.toMap(unMarshallMe)
    def toMapOf[V]()(implicit m: Manifest[V]): Map[String,V] = JsonUtil.toMap[V](unMarshallMe)
    def fromJson[T]()(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T =  JsonUtil.fromJson[T](unMarshallMe)
  }

  implicit class Marshallable[T](marshallMe: T) {
    def toJson: String = JsonUtil.toJson(marshallMe)
  }
}
```

Usage - deserialize

```
import com.some.package.json.JsonUtil.fromJson
import com.some.package.json.MarshallableImplicits._
def deserialize(json: String): MyCaseClass = fromJson[MyCaseClass](json)
```

Usage - serialize:

```
import com.some.package.json.JsonUtil.fromJson
import com.some.package.json.MarshallableImplicits._
def serialize: String = this.toJson
```

Answer (score 4):

The main idea is that you need to get rid of all `implicit Manifest` references.

As the implementation of `ClassTagExtensions` changed in Jackson Scala module 2.13.0, the answer will vary depending on the version you are using.

**Jackson Scala module 2.13+:**

Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JavaTypeable` as a replacement for `Manifest`, this fully supports nested generic types.

```scala
object JsonUtil {
  ...

  def toMap[V](json: String)(implicit m: JavaTypeable[V]): Map[String, V] = fromJson[Map[String, V]](json)

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m: JavaTypeable[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
  }
}
```

**Jackson Scala module 2.12:**

Use `ClassTag` as a replacement for `Manifest`, this does not support nested generic types though and you might want to keep using the `ScalaObjectMapper` with `Manifest`s.

```scala
object JsonUtil {
  ...

  def toMap[V](json: String)(implicit m: ClassTag[V]): Map[String, V] = fromJson[Map[String, V]](json)

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m: ClassTag[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
  }
}
```

*More details on the original issue: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/503*